What does it mean for something to be functorial (S-schemes)
Let $X,Y$ be $S$-schemes. Suppose $f: X \to Y$ is an $S$-map. Let $T$ be another $S$-scheme. Then we have an induced map $f^*: X(T) \to Y(T)$. I understand that this just sends each morphism $T \to X$ to one of the form $T \to Y$ by composition with $f$. However, I keep seeing that this induced map is functorial in $T$ which I do not understand.
My guess: this means $\operatorname{Hom}(T,-)$ is a functor on $S$-schemes (to what category I am still confused but I think sets?).
Why I care: I am interested in understanding group schemes better, and the Yoneda perspective seems to be used often, so I am trying to understand the details of how everything works. Particularly, my goal is to understand why defining group structures on all $X(T)$ suffices to define a group scheme.

Is perhaps "natural" the better term?

Functoriality in $T$ simply means that given a morphism $T \rightarrow T'$, you have the expected commutative square involving $X(T)$, $X(T')$, $Y(T)$ and $Y(T')$. In "Functoriality in $T$", $T$ should be thought of as a variable rather than a fixed scheme.

Perfect, that's exactly what I needed!
